# How to derive pressure equation from grand canonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

The pressure equation is given by
$$\frac{\beta P}{\rho} = 1-\frac{\beta \rho}{6}\int dr \cdot r \left[ \frac{dU}{dr}\right]g(r)$$

I am trying to derive it from the thermodynamic definition of pressure given by
$$\beta P = \frac{\partial \ln \Xi}{\partial V}$$
where $\Xi$ is the grand canonical partition function, with only a 2-body potential acting between particles, and $g(r)$ is the radial distribution function,$P$ is the pressure, and $\beta = 1/k_BT$.

The definition of $\Xi$ is
$$\Xi = \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^N}{N!} \int dr^N e^{-\beta U(r^N)}$$

So, employing the thermodynamic definition of pressure,
\begin{align}
\beta P &= \frac{1}{\Xi}\cdot \frac{\partial \Xi}{\partial V} \\
&= \frac{1}{\Xi}\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial V}\left( 1 + zV + \sum_{N=2}^{\infty}\int e^{-\beta U(r^N)} dr^N \right)
\end{align}

However, how do I get to the pressure equation? How do I resolve the $V$ derivative?

Comment: The usual trick is a change of variables in the position integration ($x_i'=x_i/V^{\frac{1}{3}}$).

Comment: Then the $V^{1/3}$ will simply stick outside the integral. Then it can be integrated?

Comment: also @GiorgioP, how would i resolve the potential term, $U(r^N)$?

Comment: No, in addition to a $V^N$ factor, there will be the $V$ dependence of the boltzmann factor. That is the origin of the $dU/dr$ term.

Comment: Notice that the $U$ function of your first formula is not the same as the $U(r^N)$ function in the partition function. To obtain your first formula the latter should be the sum over the pairs of a pair-wise potential $\phi(r)$, and it is $d\phi/dr$ the derivative in the first formula.